# combine two tables from excel before entering the database with php

Tags: php, excel

[image]

> this the code

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
                //It returns the highest number of rows
$total_rows = $sheet->getHighestRow();
                //It returns the highest number of columns
                $highest_column = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

                echo '<h4>Data from excel file</h4>';
                echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="responsive">';

                $query = "insert into `presensi` (`nip`, `tanggal`, `jammasuk`, `jampulang`,`jamwaktukerja`,`menitwaktukerja`) VALUES ";
                //Loop through each row of the worksheet
                for($row =2; $row <= $total_rows; $row++) {

                $single_row = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highest_column . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
```

> i write like this for combination columns C and D

```
                    $single_row3 = $sheet->rangeToArray('C' . $row . '+' . 'D' . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For range concat operator is `:` colon. Change it to below statement and it should work.

```
$single_row3 = $sheet->rangeToArray('C' . $row . ':' . 'D' . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
```

[Reference Link](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#method_rangeToArray)

Another approach is to get individual cell values (since there are only 2 columns to merge ) and concat the variables as,

```
$cellValueC = $sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue();
$cellValueD = $sheet->getCell('D' . $row)->getValue();

$concatValue = $cellValueC . ' ' . $cellValueD;
```

Comment: i try, but it show
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> float(abdul) [1]=> string(5) "rojak" } }

Comment: You will have to concat and form a string by reading the array. Have posted another approach too.